# How to address today and the following 9 days

Tags: meaning, phrasing

Would you think "the next 10 days" includes today?

If not, would there be a clearer way to put it, to refer to today and the following 9 days?

Comment: "In 9 days at the latest"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually *already* expressed it—twice—in your question.

Consider the singular case:

> I'll do it the next day.

It's a relative term. It doesn't mean today—or the specific day previously referenced in a discussion. It means the day *following*.

Similarly, *the next X days* means the plural number of days following.

If you wake up in the morning and want to express something that will happen over a 10-day period, including today, you would say:

> I'll be working on it today and the next 9 days.

There is no simpler phrasing that I can think of.

---

Note that there might be some ambiguity over the use of the word *next*.

If, at 6:00 p.m., you say *the next 10 days*, it's likely that you mean *tomorrow and the next 9 days*. Most people wouldn't bother specifying *tomorrow* in that case.

But if there's room for misinterpretation, it's always good to be explicit.

Comment: I see you're quite active on this forum, many thanks for helping out people like me. I do have a follow-up question though, if you wouldn't mind. What about "over the next 10 days" but without "including today"? Does it refer to today and the next 9 days?

Comment: @MinAndyChoi As per my updated answer, it depends on the context. Depending on when it's said, it might be taken to include today—or it might not. Different people will interpret it differently.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. Your answer really helped clear up the picture. Thank you very much.